# SSRS report new Rows table using join(lookupset)

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have multiple data in my share data set and currently i am having a problem.
When I need to get all the data using expression. I want to put in on table by rows and not in a single row. Thank you and have a great day.

=Join(LookupSet(Fields!msdyn_name.Value,Fields!msdyn_name.Value,Fields!bookableresourcebooking.Value, "DataSet2"),vbcrlf)

[image]

Comment: You can't do this unfortunately. Depending on your report design/layout you might be able to insert a subreport which takes your `msdyn_name` field as a parameter and returns all the rows as a table. If you need more help, show a sample of data and the desired report layout.

Comment: I have dataset1 which is paginated report. And this dataset2 I have data there that I need to get depending on the ID. Is this not doable in Paginated report?

Comment: You probably can but as I said before you need to show samples of data and expected output. **Edit** your question and explain in detail then you will have much more chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Hi! I found a solution already the one you told me about the subreport. I created a subreport and embedded to my paginated report.